# Matlab: Group legend entries for two plots

Tags: matlab, plot, legend

I have two 5+20 arrays, which I want to display in a single plot. However, the legend should only consist of two entries, with each individual entry referring to one of displayed plots:

```
figure; 
hold on; 
h1 = plot(hamming_intra, 'bo'); 
h2 = plot(hamming_inter, 'r+'); 
hold off;
```

If I add a legend using the `insert legend` button I get a legend with 40 entries. My goal is to get a legend with two entries (one with a red cross and one with a blue dot).

[image]

The arrays `hamming_intra` and `hamming_inter`consist of double values:

```
>> whos hamming_inter
Name               Size            Bytes  Class     Attributes

hamming_inter      5x20              800  double
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution on mathworks forums:

```
figure; 
hold on; 
h1 = plot(hamming_intra, 'bo'); 
h2 = plot(hamming_inter, 'r+'); 
hold off;
h = get(gca,'Children');
v = [h(1) h(21)]';  %in my case the first and the 21st entry correspond the the first entry of both plots
legend(v, 'data1', 'data2');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
figure; 
h1 = plot(hamming_intra, 'bo'); 
hold on
h2 = plot(hamming_inter, 'r+');
legend([h1, h2],'hamming_intra','hamming_inter')
```

Comment: That will not always work, try replacing the sets by rand(2,10) and it will fail. It depends on the formatting of your set.

Comment: I already tried this but it gives an error:

Operands to the || and && operators must be convertible to logical scalar values.

Error in legend (line 194)
    elseif narg > 0 && ~ischar(varargin{1}) && ...